# Trying to set usercontrol margins when setting left or top margins both adjust left margin only. Why?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

When I set the margins from the Mainpage both top and left both move left I cant seem to figure out why top margin moves left. I'm using Xamarin Forms 5 VS 2109.
MainPage Code

```
 <AbsoluteLayout>
            <StackLayout Rotation="90" Margin="0,0" vm:ShipImageButton.Left="10" vm:ShipImageButton.Top="0">
                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="StackShip2_Tapped" />
                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                <vm:ShipImageButton x:Name="vmShip2" ShipImage="Ship2.png" Margin="0,0" />
            </StackLayout>
       </AbsoluteLayout>

        <AbsoluteLayout>
            <StackLayout Rotation="90" vm:ShipImageButton.Left="20" vm:ShipImageButton.Top="0">
                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="StackShip3_Tapped" />
                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                <vm:ShipImageButton x:Name="vmShip3" ShipImage="Ship3.png" />
            </StackLayout>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
```

And My Usercontrol (Contentview) code is

```
 <StackLayout x:Name="ShipStack" >
        <!--Utils:Margin.Left="{StaticResource InnerPageContentMarginLeft}">-->

        <ImageButton x:Name="ShipButton"
            Rotation="0"
            CornerRadius="25"
            Margin:SetMargins.Left="{Binding LeftMargin}"
            Margin:SetMargins.Top="{Binding TopMargin}"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            BorderWidth="2"
            Padding="{StaticResource Padding_For_ImageButton}"
            Source="{Binding ShipImage}"
            BorderColor="{Binding TintColor}"
            Aspect="AspectFill"
            Clicked="Ship_Selected"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Start" />

    </StackLayout>
```

And Lastly the code to set margins Left and Top I set breakpoints and bot left and top are hit.

```
 public static Double LeftMargin { get; set; }
    public static Double TopMargin { get; set; }

    public static readonly BindableProperty LeftProperty = BindableProperty.CreateAttached(
                    propertyName: "Left",
                    returnType: typeof(double),
                    declaringType: typeof(SetMargins),
                    propertyChanged: LeftPropertyChanged,
                    defaultValue: 0.0d);

    private static void LeftPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        SetLeft(bindable, (double)newValue);
    }

    public static void SetLeft(BindableObject element, double value)
    {
        var view = element as View;
        if (view != null)
        {
            Thickness currentMargin = (Xamarin.Forms.Thickness)view.GetValue(View.MarginProperty);
            LeftMargin = currentMargin.Left;
            view.Margin = new Thickness(value, currentMargin.Top, currentMargin.Right, currentMargin.Bottom);
        }
    }

    public static double GetLeft(BindableObject element)
    {
        View view = element as View;
        if (view != null)
        {
            Thickness margin = (Xamarin.Forms.Thickness)view.GetValue(View.MarginProperty);
            TopMargin = margin.Left;
            return margin.Left;
        }
        return (double)LeftProperty.DefaultValue;
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty TopProperty = BindableProperty.CreateAttached(
                    propertyName: "Top",
                    returnType: typeof(double),
                    declaringType: typeof(SetMargins),
                    propertyChanged: TopPropertyChanged,
                    defaultValue: 0.0d);

    private static void TopPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        SetTop(bindable, (double)newValue);
    }

    public static void SetTop(BindableObject element, double value)
    {
        var view = element as View;
        if (view != null)
        {
            Thickness currentMargin = (Xamarin.Forms.Thickness)view.GetValue(View.MarginProperty);
            TopMargin = currentMargin.Top;
            view.Margin = new Thickness(value, currentMargin.Top, currentMargin.Right, currentMargin.Bottom);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand that code. It seems overly complicated. Instead of`Margin:SetMargins.Left=...` and `Top`, can't you just have a normal `Margin={Binding Margin}`, and then have your `Left` and `Top` properties update their own values PLUS re-calc the bound `Margin`?   In any case, why does `GetLeft` do `TopMargin = margin.Left;`?

Comment: Ultimately what I'm trying to achieve is the Mainpage is a game board. I needed the usercontrol to float on top of the board on Mainpage. From all the research I've done I found the only way to achieve this is with a Contentview as usercontrol. I will have several Ships aka user controls. I need to move each ship(usercontrol) independently of the other. Using only Margin Left and Margin top .

Comment: Thanks Steve. I ended up removing all the over complicated code. Went back to basics and added to the usercontrol the AbsoluteLayout Tag and binded the Margin in that tag. I posted the code below.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by creating a new test project and did the following. Yes you were right I was overthinking the problem.
in Usercontrol(ContentView) I changed it to the following

```
<AbsoluteLayout Margin="{Binding Margin}">

        <Frame x:Name="ShipStack" BorderColor="Black" >

            <AbsoluteLayout>
                <Image Source="Ship2.png"  
               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1, 1, 2, 2"  
               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"  
               Aspect="Fill"/>
            </AbsoluteLayout>
        </Frame>
        
    </AbsoluteLayout>
```

And in the MainPage I had to remove the Stacklayout Tag and only used the AbsoluteLayout Tag as follows.

```
<AbsoluteLayout >
    <ImageButton x:Name="S2" Source="Ship2.png" Rotation="90" Margin="10,60,0,0" PropertyChanged="Ship2_Changed" BorderWidth="2" BorderColor="Blue"/>
    <ImageButton x:Name="S3" Source="Ship3.png" Rotation="90" Margin="30,80,0,0"  PropertyChanged="Ship3_Changed" BorderWidth="2" BorderColor="Blue"/>
    <ImageButton x:Name="Sub3" Source="Sub3.png" Rotation="90" Margin="60,80,0,0"  PropertyChanged="Sub3_Changed" BorderWidth="2" BorderColor="Blue"/>
    <ImageButton x:Name="S4" Source="Ship4.png" Rotation="90" Margin="85,100,0,0" PropertyChanged="Ship4_Changed" BorderWidth="2" BorderColor="Blue"/>
    <ImageButton x:Name="B5" Source="BattleShip.png" Rotation="92" Margin="105,115,0,0" PropertyChanged="BattleShip_Changed" BorderWidth="2" BorderColor="Blue" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

By doing it this way I didn't need all the extra Margin code. Now I can move each ship individualy by changing the margin code in the Mainpage.
Thanks for your help it made me rethink how to resolve the problem and added the binding Margin to the Absolutelayout as I didnt want to move the frame I needed to move the whole ContentView.

Comment: By the way forgot to mention I did add the AbsoluteLayout tag to the usercontrol.

Comment: Nice use of `AbsoluteLayout`. Despite all the ways I've pushed XForms over the years, I haven't used AbsoluteLayout much. I will keep it in mind for situations that need this flexibility!